# Are braces required in if condition in perl?

Tags: perl, if-statement, curly-braces

This code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

sub marine{
    print "somestuff\n";
    exit 1;
}
$bool=1;

if($bool)
    marine();
```

Gives this error:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at ./a line 10, near ")
    marine"
    (Missing operator before marine?)
syntax error at ./a line 10, near ")
    marine"
Execution of ./a aborted due to compilation errors.
```

However, it works when there are `{}` in the `if` body. Are they required in Perl?

Answer (score 7):

For [Compound statements](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements), like yours, the braces are necessary.

```
if ($bool) {
    marine();
}
```

However, braces are not necessary for [Statement modifiers](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers):

```
marine() if $bool;
```